# Exclude folder from Zipping process in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm not overly familiar with Powershell scripting, and hoping that you may be able to help out here.

I've got this code that deletes files 'X' number of days older, and zips them and moves them to another folder. This is for space optimization.

Now in this process I need to skip a folder completely, and not process it. This is where I need help, since I don't know where to put the skip condition.

I know there are commands like `-notmatch`, but a little confused on the placement.

Code Below:

```
param([string]$destination="XXX")

$source = "XXX"

$ErrorActionPreference = “SilentlyContinue" #to avoid printing non-terminating errors


Function Clean_Drive([string]$path){ #define the function
    
    $Target = $destination + "\zip\*"
    Write-Host "*****TESTING1*****" $Target

   [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression')
    
    #Delete zip files older than 20 or more days
    if (Test-Path $Target){ 
        $lmt = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)

       Write-Verbose -Verbose "Deleting zip files:"
       Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Recurse -Force 
       Where-Object { ! $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -le $lmt } | 
       Remove-Item -Force -Verbose
    }

    $now=Get-Date 
    $files=Get-ChildItem -path $path -recurse -force -file 
    $files | Select-Object Name, fullname, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime
    $files | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name Owner -Value { (Get-Acl $this.FullName).Owner }

    # Create a variable to store columns for report variable
    $stats = "" | select Run_date, Location_of_File, Filename, DaysOfFile, LastAccessTime, Owner

    $firstArchive = ""
    $zipfile_list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new();
    $zipfile_list2 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new();
    $zipfile_list3 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new();
    $finaL_outputzipfile = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new();

    foreach ($file in $files) 
    
    
    {
               
                $day_file = [int]($now.subtract(($file.LastWriteTime))).days 
                $stats.Run_date = get-date   
                $source_file            = $file.fullname.replace($file.name, "") 
                $stats.Location_of_File = $file.fullname.replace($file.name, "") 
                $stats.DaysOfFile = $day_file
                $owner_name = @( $file.Owner.split("\") )
                $stats.Owner = $owner_name[-1]
                $stats.Filename = $file.name
                $stats.LastAccessTime = [int]($now.subtract(($file.LastAccessTime))).days
                
                # Prepare file name for name of output zip file
                $separator = “\“

                $output_reportFile = $destination + "\" + "Report_For_Dropbox_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv "

                Export-Csv -Path $output_reportFile -InputObject $stats -Append

        #For files 3 or more days, prepare to zip it up
       # if ($stats.Filename -like  "*.mp4" -OR $stats.Filename -like  "*.mov"){
       #    write-host "*****Do not delete*****" $stats.Filename}
       # else{
        if ($stats.LastAccessTime -ge 3)  {                
                              
                     # add to array
                     $zipfile_list.Add($stats.Location_of_File)
                      
        }
       # }
    }

    write-host "*****ZIPFILE_LIST*****" $zipfile_list
    write-host " "
    
     #Select only distinct value in Array
    
   $zipfile_list2 =  $zipfile_list | select -Unique

   write-host "*****ZIPFILE_LIST UNIQUE*****" $zipfile_list2
   write-host "*****TESTING2*****" $zipfile_list2.count

   for ($i=1;$i -le $zipfile_list2.count; $i++) { 
 
                $zipfile_list3 += $zipfile_list2[$i]
          
   }
    
    # de-dup again for the final list of directory to zip
    $final_zipfilelist =  $zipfile_list3 | select -Unique
    write-host "***Printing final zip list***" $final_zipfilelist

    write-host "*****TESTING3*****" $final_zipfilelist.count
    write-host " "
    
    
    # Start of zipping process
    # preparing the password
    $randomPassword = "XXX"


    for ($i=0;$i -le ($final_zipfilelist.count-1); $i++) { 

        $output_zip_filename1 = $final_zipfilelist[$i].Replace(":", "")
        $output_zip_filename1 = $output_zip_filename1.Replace("\", "_")
        $output_zip_filename1 = $output_zip_filename1.Replace(" ", "_")
        $output_zip_filename = $output_zip_filename1.substring(0, $output_zip_filename1.Length-1)

        write-host "***Output zip file name: ***" $output_zip_filename
        write-host " "

        $ZipOutputFilePath = "$($destination +"\zip\" + “OUTPUT_ARCHIVE_FOR_” + $output_zip_filename + ".zip")"
        $FilesToZip = $final_zipfilelist[$i]  + "*"


        $arguments = "a -tzip ""$ZipOutputFilePath"" ""$FilesToZip"" -mx9 -p$randomPassword"
        $windowStyle = "Normal"

        $p = Start-Process "XXX\7zip\7za.exe" -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait -PassThru -WindowStyle $windowStyle

        $output_zip_filename1 = ""      
        
    }

    if (Test-Path $ZipOutputFilePath){
            for($i=0; $i -le $final_zipfilelist.Count; $i++){
            Remove-Item -Path $final_zipfilelist[$i] -Recurse | where $stats.LastAccessTime -ge 3
            }
     }                               
   
}


Clean_Drive $source
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $now = Get-Date
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -File |
        # add exception here
        # where file's ($_) directory's name does not equal (-ne) 'SomeFolderName'
        Where-Object { $_.Directory.Name -ne 'SomeFolderName' }

    $files | Select-Object Name, fullname, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime
    $files | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name Owner -Value { (Get-Acl $this.FullName).Owner }
```

Comment: Very helpful, Daniel! That did the job. Appreciate it very much.